# Why does reassigning to another type trigger VSCode's type checker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

So here's the simplified snippet from a react app:

```
let text = "Lorem ipsum";
 //**manipulation of text**
if (bold) text = <b>{text}</b>;
return <button>{text}</button>;
```

This should work fine, since JSX doesn't care if the content between {} is plaintext or an HTML element. However, VSCode displays the following error:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2322)
```

I thought the type checking service is to prevent runtime errors, so why would it flag this?

Comment: Could you change `text` type to element by using `let text = <>Lorem impsum</>`?

Comment: Well, text is actually a little more complex, and I've edited the post to reflect that. So I can't really add those tags that easily as if it were just a literal. Btw, I didn't even know that <> was a thing.

Comment: `<></>` is equivalent to `React.Fragment`

Comment: Are you working in a `.jsx` or a `.tsx` file? If it's `.tsx`, just say `let text: Element | string = ...`. If it's just `.jsx`, add an eslint ignore line

Comment: Its javascript. .js. I would like to disable the error altogether, not just ignore specific instances. - Also I never said it was eslint